# Only allow certain characters to be entered in html textinput

Tags: javascript, character, limit, textfield

I just need to allow a user to enter the following characters in the textinput:

a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|

```
<form action="http://www.cknuckles.com/cgi/echo.cgi" method="get" name="logOn">
  User Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="userName" size="25" /><br />
  Password:<br />
  <input type="password" name="pw" size="25" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Log In" onClick="validate()"/> 
</form>
```

Above is my HTML, and Below is my JavaScript I tried to use to validate it - but it doesnt work - any clues.

```
<script language="javascript">
   document.logOn.onsubmit=validate;

   function validate(){

var name=document.logOn.pw.value;
    if(!name = "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]"){              
alert("Your Password Cant Have any thing other than a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_| - Play It Straight!");
    return false;
}               

    return true;
}

</script>
```

But This isnt working. I can still put chars in like ">" and "<" and "{" etc.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: where exactly you are getting stuck?

Comment: I want to allow a user to enter only these characters: a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_| to enter in a password field. I don't want him to enter other than these characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 restricting input characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607278/html5-restricting-input-characters)

Comment: Article
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-dom-allow-enter-particular-characters-only-aniket-jha/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can change your input text as below:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]{6,25}" />
```

So the code changes look like below:

```
    <form action="#" method="get">
       User Name:<br />
       <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]{6,25}" /><br />
       Password:<br />
       <input type="password" /><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Log In" /> 
   </form>
```

This will work without using JavaScript. `pattern` can be used instead. It is more effective than JavaScript for form validation.

Comment: nope.. I'm still able to put '>' '<' '{' '}' in the text field :(

Comment: i have a question,how does this do `alert` or other event

Comment: @baburao113: yes, i know u are able to type it. but when you click on Login button then it inputtext will notify that the specified value is incorrect. and will request user to please match the required format. try it. it will work. it works fine for me.

Comment: @bull-T when user click on Login button then the input text will not notify you as `"please match the requested format"` hope you got understood the method. try it. it will work.

Comment: But if a user(hacker) changes/removes the pattern from the client side using Inspect, he can still send that data to the database.

Comment: @asterisk a hacker can also track the messages being sent, and use that information to generate their own calls to that location, so it doesn't matter what the front end does, it can be skipped.  The API should always do validation on it.

Answer (score 6):

use this

```
<script language="javascript">
document.logOn.onsubmit=validate;

function validate(){

var name=document.logOn.pw.value;
var reg=/[^a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\*\_\|]+/;
if(reg.test(name)){              
alert("Your Password Cant Have any thing other than a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_| - Play It    Straight!");
return false;
}               

return true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: There's no need for Javascript for form validation.

Comment: `if(reg.test(name)){`: passing the test, the test is ok. Why `return false`?

Comment: @Timo It looks like the `var reg` checks for anything outside the acceptable range of characters - see the message in their `alert`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
<input type="text" name="something" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]{0,100}">
```

Answer (score 3):

## Invalid Inputs

Many times we want to make validations on an input box for characters that user can type. And other characters will not be entertained in the input box.

> Question: Make a input box that accepts **digits** and **spaces** only.  Also, care for copy-paste (Ctrl +V ) of invalid characters.

The first step is to register event on input tag. But what event type?  We are typing characters into it so `keypress` event looks fine.

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
var currentInputValue = '';
input.addEventListener('keypress', function inputKeypressHandler(e) {
    // keypress event on input box is listened here and this function is triggered
    // which key is pressed, keyPressed = e.which || e.keyCode; 
    const key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    // key code corresponds to digits 0-9 or space then okay
    // 0-9 key code is 48-57
    // space keycode is 32
    const SPACE = 32; // May be just stored somewhere
    const ZERO = 48;
    const NINE = 57;
    // valid digit is b/w 0-9 thus invalid will be lt 0 or gt 9
    const isNotValidDigit = key < ZERO || key > NINE;
    // if key is not a space or not a digit prevent this event
    if (key != SPACE || ( isNotValidDigit ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This is pretty good solution but this doesn't prevent paste cheats. And that is because the `keypress` event only records key pressed inside input box.
A better event type is requried. `input` it runs on  all input ways including copy paste and drag.

```js
var currentInputValue = '';
input.addEventListener('input', function inputInputEventHandler(e) {
    // use target of event to get value of input
    const target = e.target;
    // we can use regex to check if current input value
    // is valid input
    const DIGITS_SPACE_REGEX = /^[0-9\s]*$/;
    // test if target.value or value of input box now is valid.
    // if value is valid then update currentInputValue 
    // target.value else its is not value and we will
    // ignore this target.value and replace it with 
    // previously valid value currentInputValue
    DIGITS_SPACE_REGEX.test(target.value) 
        ? ( currentInputValue = target.value ) 
        : ( target.value = currentInputValue );
});
```

This solves our problem of paste  but there is one problem here. Say you paste something `Ctrl/Cmd + V` your current cursor position will be lost and moved to starting. This must not haapen and you must be able to retain  cursor position.

```js
// Track cursor position
// cursor position is changed when you type something
const cursorState = {};
input.addEventListener('keydown', function inputKeydownHandler(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    // record the start and end
    cursorState.selectionStart = target.selectionStart;
    cursorState.selectionEnd = target.selectionEnd;
});
```

now in `input` handler

```js
// modify
DIGITS_SPACE_REGEX.test(target.value) 
        ? ( currentInputValue = target.value ) 
        : ( target.value = currentInputValue );
 // to
 if (DIGITS_SPACE_REGEX.test(target.value)) {
     currentValue = target.value;
 }
 else {
    target.value = current.value;
    // restore cursor state
    target.setSelectionRange(
        cursorState.selectionStart,
        cursorState.selectionEnd
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and revert me back if it works for you

```
function validate(){
        var name=document.logOn.pw.value;
        var test = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]");
        if(!name.match(test)){              
           alert("Your Password Cant Have any thing other than a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_| - Play It                     Straight!");
        return false;
  }               
   return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KJEcG/

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
if(!/[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]./.test(name)){
```