# Restrict user input

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm currently trying to restrict users so they can only input letters or numbers in a textbox and if anything other than letters or numbers is typed in I want to remove the value.

So my regex looks like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` and the whole jQuery functions looks as follows:

```
 $("#myInputField").keyup(function (e) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, '');
    }
});
```

but this seems to be doing the opposite. So if I type a number or letter in then it's replaced and it's allowing all the other characters. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: Use a negated character class, `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '')`

Comment: Yes, it's the opposite as you're looking for alphanumeric, then removing alphanumeric.  I've not tried this (so only a comment), but possibly: `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g/, '');`

Comment: And the test would be `if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(this.value))` or `if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/).test(this.value)))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still the same issue

Comment: @freedomn-m still the same issue

Comment: Yes, because you test the input against an opposite regex. It must be `if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(this.value)) {`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just made the change as you mentioned and it allows me to input anything now

Comment: If you want to remove the value, why not just put `this.value = ''`?

Comment: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Quite possible. The problem is not just with the regex, but with how it is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only allow certain characters to be entered in html textinput](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434174/only-allow-certain-characters-to-be-entered-in-html-textinput)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is currently this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Breaking that down, that matches the start of the string, then as many as possible *alphanumeric* characters, then the end of the string.

What you actually want to match is any *non-alphanumeric* characters, and you don't care where the start or end of the string is.

As such, the regex as suggested in the comments is correct:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

This matches any *non-alphanumeric* characters.

You must change this in **both** the test and replacement lines. Furthermore, somebody can right-click and paste into the textbox, so this isn't foolproof (someone can also disable JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for this, the paste issue can I not just do `$('#validate-serial').bind("paste", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });` after the if condition?

Comment: You can try to prevent a Paste, but I suggest you *don't*. Copy+Paste is integral to computers, just like the Back button (I've seen sites that break the Back button). You could check the input onChange or onBlur, but again *the user can disable JavaScript*, so you **must** check it server-side.

Comment: On the server side the input is checked to ensure it's always numbers/letters

Comment: If you're checking server-side, then I wouldn't worry too much about client-side validation. Make it good enough to stop accidental errors, but anything else is extra effort. Your keyup function is probably good enough, I would also check `blur` for when the textbox is unfocused (this catches pastes etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the further information I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you change your regex in both locations to `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` it resolves the issue. Basically your regex is almost always true and even when it is false it acts true because something else negates it to be true. I have added an example with example code. I also use the console to prove it.

```js
 $("#myInputField").keyup(function (e) {
   console.log(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(this.value));
    if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, '');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInputField"/>
```

** At the time of this posting there is an answer. They have better wording. Mine just provides an example that I worked on.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, use `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` to find any string that does not conform to only letters or numbers.

Note that the `String.replace` function returns the string with the replacement. The string called on `String.replace` is not adjusted.

```
$("#myInputField").keyup(function (e) {
   if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(this.value)) {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
   }
});
```

@Cayce K Thanks for pointing out that the other symbols should be removed :)

Comment: I don't believe they want it emptied.. Just the character that is added removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex at both places (in your condition as well as in replace statement)

***[^\d\w]***

This is negated set, which match any character which is not in set(i.e. anything other than alpha numeric).