# Validate/Restrict zalgo texts in Javascript

Tags: unicode

Can I validate a user from entering zalgo texts to a form or any other place which prompts a data save, as explained in [Zalgo Texts]: [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only allow certain characters to be entered in html textinput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434174/only-allow-certain-characters-to-be-entered-in-html-textinput)

Comment: I went through that question. But the answer is not complete for me and  allows several characters in

Comment: Give precise examples of what you want to prevent and where you want to prevent it. Do you just want to only allow ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your need you can use the following to validate a string as such. 
Furthermore you can use [strip-combining-marks](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/strip-combining-marks) if you want to remove Unicode combining marks from strings.

```js
function validateZalgo(s) {
    return /[^\u+0300-\u+036F]/.test(s);
}

var isValidated = validateZalgo('asd̨͈̺̱̤͚̤͚̤͚͈̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆');

alert(isValidated);
```

Comment: But wouldn't that disallow characters like "€", "α", "", which are all clearly not Zalgo text?

Comment: @lenz true. It would, let me fix my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it disallows "a few characters". From the 130k assigned codepoints in Unicode, it allows 256. Your approach disallows more than 99.8% of all possible characters.

Comment: Also, your approach allows "á", but not "ć". Would you say the second one is Zalgo, and the first one isn't? I'm curious why you chose exactly this range.

Comment: @lenz I think it's proper if the range is changed and updated as

return /[^\u+0300-\u+036F]/.test(s);

Range taken from 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: Now that's definitely more related to Zalgo text! There are a couple more combining characters if you scroll down on WP, and I personally would only call it Zalgo if they are used excessively, but let's leave all that as an exercise to the OP. It's not clear what they meant by "Zalgo" anyway.