# HTML5 input attribute UTF-8, min/max, no special characters

Tags: html, validation, input, utf-8

For first validation of an input in HTML5 I want to use the pattern attribute.
What I have so far is:

`<INPUT name="firstname" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" title="2 more characters">`

How can I include names that contain other UTF-88 characters but no special signs like question marks, commas and so on?

I think its clear what I want. The user should be able to type only valid first names. That includes "ü", "ñ" and many others.

Comment: Of course I meant UTF-8

Comment: Could you specify which other non-alphabetic characters you want to include? Or do you mean that you only want to include alphabetic characters?

Comment: All UTF-8 alphabetic characters, space and '-'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only allow certain characters to be entered in html textinput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434174/only-allow-certain-characters-to-be-entered-in-html-textinput)

Comment: No, its not because i have to include all UTF-8 alphabetic characters. That includes i.e. "ü", "ñ" and many others.

Comment: Aside of that the suggested "possible duplicate" is javascript and I dont want to use that for this specific form.

Comment: check only HTML input - js is 2nd level of validation in that question