# User input sometimes breaks REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code to filter a list based on what the user types in an input field:

```
const searchQuery = e.target.value.trim();

items
  .filter((item) =>
    item.title.match(new RegExp(searchQuery, 'gi'))
  )
  .map(item => {
    // Do something...
  });
```

it works great except everything breaks when the user enters some funky text in the input field like:

```
//on\/: \/: \
```

Results in the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: ///on\/: \/: \/: \ at end of pattern
```

How to approach this correctly so that my code doesn't break based on user input?

Comment: if you want to allow for a regex in the input then you have to let the user know if the regex is wrong, otherwise you need to create a regex based on general user input urself by prepending and appending to the input

Comment: @MozenRath I don't want to allow the user to enter REGEX, I just want to prevent my code form breaking if they do (either on purpose or by accident). So I guess I want to know how to "escape" the user's input if that's the right word.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434174/only-allow-certain-characters-to-be-entered-in-html-textinput

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of a duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to perform escapes, or some type of validation.  Here's a link to the [JavaScript escape() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp).  I hope that helps.