# input pattern='[a-zA-Z]' is not working in React application

Tags: javascript, regex, html, reactjs, react-redux

What I have been working on is a text `input` that narrows down `<option>` in a `<select>` as the user types. It is working, but my concern now is security, what a user passes into the `input`, and potential malicious entries.

I figured I could do something like `<input placeholder='[a-zA-Z]' />` but it is still allowing other characters to be entered into the text box.

What am I doing wrong here, and what would be an alternative that would permit only alphanumeric being entered?

```
onInputChange(term) {
    this.setState({ term });
}

renderOptionsSelect(term) {
    return _.map(this.props.pos_list, p => {
        var searchTerm = this.state.term.toLowerCase();
        if (p.pos_code.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm)) {
            return (
                <option key={p.pos_code} value={p.pos_code}>{p.pos_code}</option>
            );                        
        }
    });
}

// render the main element of the container
render() {
    return (
        <div className='panel panel-default'>
            <div className='panel-heading'>
                <h4><strong>Basic Query</strong></h4>
            </div>

            <div className='panel-body'>
                <input 
                    pattern='[a-zA-Z]'
                    className='form-control' 
                    placeholder='Enter Keyword or Position Code' 
                    value={this.state.term}
                    onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
                />

                <hr />
                <h4>Position:</h4>
                <select className='form-control'>
                    <option></option>
                    {this.renderOptionsSelect()}
                </select>
                <br />
                <h4>Data Cut:</h4>
                <select className='form-control' disabled={true} />

            </div>
        </div>
    ); 
}
```

Comment: The `pattern` attribute is only enforced when a form is submitted. It's not very easy to restrict the characters allowed in an input like this, it's much easier to validate the input upon submission.

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like if I want the validation to happen instantaneously, I need to do JS validation probably in the `onInputChange(term)`.

Comment: What kind of malicious input are you worried about? The search looks like it's happening locally so you can just validate before you submit whatever this form is part of. You could validate on changes, but it will slow down your search even further and seems unnecessary.

Comment: Also, I don't know whether you are interested or don't want the dependency, but check this out: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete . It seems like what you want.

Comment: Malicious input, and also currently if someone enters any `()\` it generates a RegEx error in the console which just looks unprofessional. Figure I can prevent that even if someone accidentally types one of those characters. (Yeah, most users aren't looking at the console).

Comment: You do realise that a malicious client can bypass client-side security checks? You need to fix the server so that it doesn't do anything stupid on invalid input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's easy. You:

1. Remove the pattern attribute.
2. Register your `onInputChange` method for `input` events instead of `change` events (`onInput={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}`).
3. Clean up the received value in the `onInputChange` before changing the state.

Comment: But seriously, client side JS and security checks? :(. You should reconsider whether you need that in the first place.

Comment: It's not about security - it's about UX. Would you rather wait for the server to validate your input when you could have it validated at an instant?

Comment: When you remove the onChange handler and use onInput instead, React will throw a console error complaining that onChange is missing.  To suppress this, you can create an onChange handler that does nothing, like this: onChange={() => {}}

Answer (score 4):

Check my answer in details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052651/13607767

Here it is in brief -

State

```
const [tagInputVal, setTagInputVal] = useState("");
```

Input tag

```
<input id="tag-input" type="text" placeholder="Add a tag" value={tagInputVal} onChange={(e) => onChangeTagInput(e)}></input>
```

Handler function

```
function onChangeTagInput(e) {
    setTagInputVal(e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/ig, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For React Typescript users.

I found this snippet very helpful…

```
const regex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");
```

> This regular expression force to use at least: one number, one capital
> letter, one lowercase letter, one special character and 8 character
> long password.

Then you can use it like this…

```
const [strongPassword, setStrongPassword] = useState(false);

function handleChangeValue(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (regex.test(event.target.value)) {
        setStrongPassword(true);
    } else {
        setStrongPassword(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Or the simplest way to make this work is,*

Put your `handleSubmit` function in the < form > tag as `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` instead of on a button separately.

This will also make other input attributes such as pattern, type, required.

Answer (score -2):

So you currently have the functionality of narrowing down the options of the `<select>` as the user types, and now your concern is increasing security by limiting what the user is able to submit as input.

The answer to this concern is that **it is not possible to secure input with client-side validation; it must be done with server-side validation**.

Client-side security checks can easily be bypassed. The input must be checked when it is received by the server in order to make sure that it is not malicious.