# How to input only depending on the pattern

Tags: html, input

im not sure if this is possible but I want an input box where the user can only type in the following pattern: (Number)(-)(Number)(Number)(Letter)

The user cannot type anything else but this pattern. Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37319683/1685196)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 restricting input characaters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607278/html5-restricting-input-characaters)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex (what you specify in the "pattern" value):

```
<input type="text" pattern="regex comes here">
```

And in your case i believe you will need this regex:

```
[\d][-][\d][\d][a-zA-Z]
```